# how to draw networkX graph in flask?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, networkx

I am trying to to draw a graph with networkx and then show it in my flask webpage, but I dont know how to show it in my flask app? I used matplotlib but I am keep running to errors. I dont know how to do this part!

Any help would be appreciate it!

```
@app.route('/graph')
def graph_draw():
    F = Figure()

    G = nx.Graph()   
    G.add_node(1)
    G.add_nodes_from([2, 3])
    H = nx.path_graph(10)
    G.add_nodes_from(H)
    G.add_node(H)
    G.add_edge(1, 2)
    nx.draw(G)
    p = plt.show()

return render_template('indexExtra.html',p=p)
```

Comment: Show us some code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón I Just added to the question! thank you

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón is there any way I can return the graph in a specific html file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flask's function [`send_file`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=send_file#flask.send_file), which accepts either a filename or a file-like object, to create a route for the image and use another route to show the image inside a template.

You can save your graph plot like this:

```
nx.draw(G)
with open(filepath, 'wb') as img:
    plt.savefig(img)
    plt.clf()
```

As a more complete example here's something I did some time ago, a flask app that renders the `n-th` complete graph with at the route `/<int:nodes>`:

## server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
import networkx as nx


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<int:nodes>')
def ind(nodes):
    return render_template("image.html", nodes=nodes)

@app.route('/graph/<int:nodes>')
def graph(nodes):
    G = nx.complete_graph(nodes)
    nx.draw(G)

    img = BytesIO() # file-like object for the image
    plt.savefig(img) # save the image to the stream
    img.seek(0) # writing moved the cursor to the end of the file, reset
    plt.clf() # clear pyplot

    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## templates/image.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Graph</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Graph</h1>
    <img
       src="{{ url_for('graph', nodes=nodes) }}"
       alt="Complete Graph with {{ nodes }} nodes"
       height="200"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I couldn't find anything online! I appreciate it!

Comment: How can I return the graph/Image to a specific html page?